AWS Step-Function RedriveExecution
Is there a way to pass multiple execution ARN's to the redrive-execution API.
Use Case: To initiate redrive-execution API for the failed step functions at once.

What is the importance of "at once"? Anyway these are long running processes that are not synchronized and even if they are started together, they will progress independently.
Anyway, the API supports a single ARN. You can run it multiple times and even in parallel if needed.
